# warnings while trying to compile old linux kernel with gcc 12.1.0

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, gcc-warning

I am currently hunting a bug using git bisect in linux staging-testing tree.

Some commits are giving following errors after I try to build them:

```
subcmd-util.h:58:31: error: pointer may be used after ‘realloc’ [-Werror=use-after-free]
   58 |                         ret = realloc(ptr, 1);
check.c:2867:58: error: ‘%d’ directive output may be truncated writing between 1 and 10 bytes into a region of size 9 [-Werror=format-truncation=]
 2867 |                 snprintf(pvname, sizeof(pvname), "pv_ops[%d]", idx);
```

I tried adding `-Wno-error=use-after-free` to `KBUILD_FLAGS` in main Makefile, tried adding

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += $(call cc-disable-warning, use-after-free)
```

I even tried removing `-Werror` from `CFLAGS` in Makefile in folder where problematic files are located, but nothing worked.

More information:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.artixlinux.org/ --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --enable-link-serialization=1
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.1.0 (GCC)
```

Linux staging tree: `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gregkh/staging.git`.

One of the commits that gives following warnings: `2ab9c9675fe892e7fe9fa8c0a6125e2b40d2889d`.

Comment: How about putting some `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "stuff"` into the offending source file directly? Kbuild is a complex system, it may be caching the compiler flags and what not.

Comment: Can you use an earlier version of GCC so that the build does not stumble when the GCC 12 related fixes have been bisected out? You can specify the C compiler to use on the `make` command line, e.g. `make CC=gcc-11` (assuming you still have GCC 11 installed as /usr/bin/gcc-11).

Comment: maybe those are the bugs you are hunting

Comment: You need to define "old". Linux kernel sources are in general not forward-compatible with new compilers. You cannot compile old kernels with the latest version of GCC, switch to an older compiler. I honestly wouldn't expect even the latest kernel to support the latest GCC version, compiler support needs time. Look at the file `Documentation/process/changes.rst` in your kernel sources for an adequate GCC version and use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compile older version of kernel I needed older compiler ("Linux kernel sources are in general not forward-compatible with new compilers"). In my case the kernel version was 5.16.0 and I could compile it with gcc 11. If you have gcc 11 specific warnings then try gcc 10 and so on.

Except CC flags, I also needed set to HOSTCC flags to use gcc-11 compiler:

```
make HOSTCC=gcc-11 CC=gcc-11
```

Comment: If someone has another solution regarding my initial approach described in question feel free to make another comment/answer. Thanks to everyone who commented.